# Locators (CSS selector or xPATH) for Angular based applications

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor

We have a small angularJs application and I want to write some automation test scripts leveraging the current SeleniumWebDriver-java-testNG framework. I am concerned about writing reliable locators being new to Angular applications. Following is the example html code:

```
<div class="item  ng-scope active" ng-class="$index===0 ? 'active' : ''" ng-repeat="plan in Plans">
        <section class="container">
            <div class="card" ng-class="{'flipped':isFlipped}" ng-click="isFlipped =! isFlipped">
                <div class="back">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10" id="restore-title">
                            <span class="ng-binding">Basic Subscription</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 restoreImg">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/restore_black.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 restore">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10 disclaimer">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--<section class="planBtn-wrapper">-->
            <!--<div class="row planBtn">-->
                <!--<div class="col-xs-5 minusBtn">-->
                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" style="border: 5px solid gainsboro" ng-click="removePlan()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"-->
                            <!--ng-click="removePlan(plan,$index)">-->
                        <!--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>-->
                    <!--</button>-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div class="col-xs-2 textPlan">-->
                    <!--<span>{{order.plan[$index].count}}</span>-->
                <!--</div>-->
                <!--<div class="col-xs-5 plusBtn">-->
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" ng-click="addPlan(plan,$index)">-->
                        <!--<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                <div class="row planBtn">
                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 minusBtn">
                        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" style="border: 5px solid gainsboro" ng-click="removePlan()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg center-block" ng-click="removePlan(plan,$index)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 textPlan">
                        <span class="ng-binding">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 plusBtn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" ng-click="addPlan(plan,$index)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here I want to write a locator for the button : `i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"` (this is an 'Add Item'  button with symbol "+" displayed on UI). Currently i have written the following css selector and it seems to work fine.

```
By.cssSelector("div.item.ng-scope.active i[class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus']")
```

1. Is there a better/more reliable approach to locate this element?

By talking to team members (developers) and with some online research (including looking at other questions and feedback on StackOverflow), I think that using `class="item  ng-scope active"` for locating elements may not be a good approach. I also realized that using protractor-javascript may be a better stack choice to test angular application, but my current scope is using selenium-java-testNG.

2. If using ng-scope is not a good approach then what could be the alternate way? Any general suggestions locating elements for angular based applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that using class="item  ng-scope active" for locating elements may not be a good approach

This is definitely true. `ng-scope` itself is not a good choice to rely your locator on. Same goes for "glyphicon" and "glyphicon-plus" which are UI style specific locators and not "data-driven".

I would use the following locator:

```
div.item.active button[ng-click^=addPlan]
```

I've removed the `ng-scope` class check since you don't have to check all of the classes - `item` and `active` are enough to be included into the selector. Then, we are looking for the `button` element that has `ng-click` attribute that starts with `addPlan`. This would not only uniquely match the button, but is also quite readable and to the point.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. A follow up question, I see `class="ng-binding"` is also used in the html. Can this be used to write the locators or as you suggested, I should look for alternate locators?

Comment: @AGill `ng-binding` is similar to `ng-scope` in a way that it's not a good class to rely your locators on. Usually, if there is `ng-binding` class present - it's likely you may use `by.binding()` location technique to locate the element. Glad to help.